# Theme get blocks

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm trying to get a list of all blocks for a certain path but can't figure how to do that.

For example, on the page at url "node/5", I have a few blocks on different regions (sidebars, content bottom, footer). I need to get a list of all these blocks that should be rendered on this page (node/5)

**UPDATE:**

this seems to work but only for the "content" region.

```
global $theme;
$all_regions = system_region_list($theme);
$blocks = array();
foreach (array_keys($all_regions) as $region) {
  $blocks += block_list($region);
}
```

Before this piece of code I run `menu_execute_active_handler('node/2', false)` because i want to get the blocks for a specific path (Eg: node/2). Unfortunately, it only grab the "content" blocks, no header/footer blocks

Any ideeas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_load_blocks/7)Already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673773/in-drupal-7-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-blocks-being-used-on-the-page) before at stackoverflow

```
  global $theme;
  $all_regions = system_region_list($theme);
  $blocks = array();
  foreach (array_keys($all_regions) as $region) {
    $blocks += block_list($region);
  }
```

this code will tell about all blocks on current page.

**Updated:**

check if dpm([_block_load_blocks()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_load_blocks/7)); helps you

Comment: this is weird. it only shows blocks from the "content" region. With any other custom region it won't work :(((

Comment: did you miss to clear the caches after adding the custom regions

Comment: no, caches are cleared. I just updated the question, maybe you can have a look? thanks